# How do I convert List<T> to IEnumerable<class> in OnModelCreating

Tags: c#, .net-core, fluent

I have a Dotnet Core api where I'm separating out the api, domain logic, and data access into separate projects.  Everything was previously all crammed into the api project.  My project structure is as follows:

API - The web api project
Core - Defines all interfaces used throughout the solution
Domain - Uses the interfaces defined in the core project to define the domain classes and logic
Data - The data access layer that communicates with the database and processes the info

Before I defined interfaces everything worked fine but know I'm receiving a CS0266 error.  The interfaces are defined in the core project so the relationships between objects are represented by interfaces.  As an example my game interface is as follows:

```
using System;

namespace SudokuCollective.Core.Interfaces.Models
{
    public interface IGame : IEntityBase
    {
        int UserId { get; set; }
        IUser User { get; set; }
        int SudokuMatrixId { get; set; }
        ISudokuMatrix SudokuMatrix { get; set; }
        int SudokuSolutionId { get; set; }
        ISudokuSolution SudokuSolution { get; set; }
        bool ContinueGame { get; set; }
        int AppId { get; set; }
        DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        DateTime DateCompleted { get; set; }
        bool IsSolved();
    }
}
```

My user interface is as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SudokuCollective.Core.Interfaces.Models
{
    public interface IUser : IEntityBase
    {
        string UserName { get; set; }
        string FirstName { get; set; }
        string LastName { get; set; }
        string NickName { get; set; }
        string FullName { get; }
        string Email { get; set; }
        string Password { get; set; }
        bool IsActive { get; set; }
        DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
        DateTime DateUpdated { get; set; }
        ICollection<IGame> Games { get; set; }
        ICollection<IUserRole> Roles { get; set; }
        ICollection<IUserApp> Apps { get; set; }
        void ActivateUser();
        void DeactiveUser();
        void UpdateRoles();
    }
}
```

As you can see the relationship between the users and games is represented by an IUser interface in the game interface and by a collection of IGame in the user interface.  These use to be classes but I've changed them interfaces since they are defined in the core project and the classes are defined in the domain project.

However, now I'm getting the following error in my OnModelCreating method in my DBContext file:

```
Error   CS0266  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<SudokuCollective.Core.Interfaces.Models.IGame>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<SudokuCollective.Domain.Models.Game>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

The relationship is established here:

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<Game>()
                .HasOne(game => game.User)
                .WithMany(user => user.Games)
                .HasForeignKey(game => game.UserId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

How can I convert 'System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<SudokuCollective.Core.Interfaces.Models.IGame>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<SudokuCollective.Domain.Models.Game>'?

Comment: The project can be reviewed here: https://github.com/Joseph-Anthony-King/SudokuCollective/tree/refactor

Comment: Alternative approach to separate data objects and behaviour objects then you can get rid of Core project (Domain project will define both data and behaviour)

Comment: Thank you Fabio, it looks like I'll have to go that route.

Comment: I downloaded the example project from github but it doesn't compile. SudokuCollective.Api.csproj seems to be missing.

Comment: Hey AntiqTech!  Yeah, the project was a mess.  I refactored the project in an api, a core to hold all definitions, and a data project to hold data and behavior.  It's not as elegant as I would have liked but it is currently working.  Please be sure to try the refactor tree listed above.  Thanks to everyone for reviewing this!

Comment: I wish the fluent API could work with interface types.